# Android In-app billing app apk

Tags: android, apk, in-app-billing

I am in the last phase of developing my android app. And I am planning to upload it to play store.

I included in-app billing in my app. and the license key for in-app billing is hard coded in the app.

The situation I am worried about is, someone get my app apk and do reverse engineer to get the code and he modified the app with new interface and changed the license key. then published the app in his account. like this users will do purchases to his account and the app will give permission to download the purchased items from my server.

Is there a way that hackers can get my apk?
Is that possible. and how can I prevent that.

Comment: Have you tried to google before asking that question?